# Skipping to the next object in a for loop after n seconds?

Tags: python, instaloader

ookay, so I'm in a bit of a pickle here.

This is my code:

```py
profiles = [profiles here]
f_profiles = [formatted profiles go here, this is useless, im just doing this to make the printing stuff look more pretty]

DAILY_SCHEDULED_TIME = "6:00"


def routine():

    print(colored(f"Getting from {f_profiles}"))
    for profile in profiles:
        print(colored(f"\nFetching from: {profile}\n"))
        os.system(f"instaloader {profile} --no-video-thumbnails --no-captions --no-metadata-json --no-compress-json --no-profile-pic --dirname-pattern={os.getcwd()}\\media\\")

def attemptRoutine():
    while(1):
        try:
            routine()
            break
        except OSError as err:
            print("Routine Failed on " + "OS error: {0}".format(err))
            time.sleep(60*60)

#attemptRoutine()
schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(attemptRoutine)

attemptRoutine()
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()  
    time.sleep(60) # wait one min
```

what this does is just download memes so my other script can send them as an SMS to my phone.

> Essentially what my problem here is, is that this script goes on forever. It'll download 100's of photos and videos from a profile when I only really need around 12 per user.

> I'm in a pickle here because It's a for loop for ever profile in profiles
> so I need a way to quit what im doing with one profile, so it can move on to the next in a certain amount of time.

e.g

```
profile 1 -> Downloading memes. 
(20 secs pass)
profile 1 -> quits -> profile 2 starts

etc and etc
```

but what is going on now:

```
profile 1 -> Downloading memes
(20 secs pass)
profile 1 -> Downloading Memes
(1 hour pass)
profile 1 -> Downloading memes
etc etc
```

this is because as I stated above, there are 100's of 1000's of photos and videos on the profiles. sooo, that's a bit of a prob.

How can I do this??

**TL;DR**
I want to make a timer in a for loop. so that it could stop what its doing and continue with another object in the list (for loop) after a certain amount of time

Essentially, I want to skip to the next iteration in my for loop after `n` seconds.

If someone can help, please do so, any and all help would be appreciated though if you could  dumb-down what I should do, how it works or things like that, that'd be appreciated also.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your code is utilizing [instaloader](https://instaloader.github.io/cli-options.html), then it looks like the documentation specifies that there is a `--count` parameter that you could specify the number of posts to download:

```
--count COUNT, -c
Do not attempt to download more than COUNT posts. Applies to #hashtag, %location_id, :feed, and :saved.
```